# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout problem

Tags: android

I have a problem with Android Studio:

```
Error:(7, 35) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element
'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'.
```

It is in an empty project. I can't find the solution.

Comment: Have you added the dependency   implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
 to your gradle file?

Comment: Do post your code as well as no one able to understand what you have coded

Comment: @GregorRant Yes, I've added to gradle file... Android Studio has added :-)

Comment: @SurajBahadur It is an empty project in Android Studio... "Hello World!" :-)

Comment: Have you find any solutions. buddy?